# dapper issue with multi query causing loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, dapper

Hi I have the following:

```
 public static RawData GetReportData(string connectionString, string UserGuid, string Report_Id)
    {

        var Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        using (var dbc = Connection)
        {
            var multi = dbc.QueryMultiple("myStoredProc", new { UserGuid, Report_Id }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            // get the model Id
            var Id = multi.Read<dynamic>().ToList();
            var mId = Id.First().model_ID;

            // get the report data
            var theData = multi.Read<dynamic>().ToList();

            var f = new RawData();
            //var thisworks = new List<dynamic>();

            f.Model_Id = mId;
            f.rdata =  theData;

            return f;
        }

    }
```

RawData is this model:

```
public class RawData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Model_Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> rdata { get; set; }
}
```

The stored proc returns two data sets. The first contains a list with one row and containing an ID. The second contains a report with a varying data structure.  The Dapper code works fine and the correct data is returned.

However as soon as I try and return this data in my model the code executes without error but then appears to come back and try and execute the multi query again. It's very odd.

If I do this then it works:

```
var thisworks = new List<dynamic>();
f.rdata = thisworks;  //theData;
```

Am I doing something dumb?  Can anyone spot anything obvious? Perhaps I've been staring at this too long?

Comment: I think this is not a Dapper issue. I swapped out the Dapper code for ADO.net and got the same issue.

Comment: I think this is the issue:  public IEnumerable<dynamic> rdata { get; set; } But I don't know why yet.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been caused by the dynamic data type. I got rid of that and used a big class containing several static lists which would usually be empty and the problem went away.